# How do I write the equation of a rational function given these characteristics

Tags: rational-functions

1. $Y$ intercept at $-5$
2. **No** $x$ intercepts
3. Discontinuous points at $(-1,-5)$ and $(3, -5)$

This was on an assignment, please help!
Edit: the graph is NOT linear

Comment: Is the assignment to write the equation of *any* function that satisfies these characteristics?  Are you allowed to write a piecewise equation (i.e. $f(x)$ when $a < x < b$, but $g(x)$ otherwise)?

Comment: Yes, but I am asked for an exact equation so piecewise would not work unfortunately. (any equation that satisfies these characteristics)

Comment: Equations are not functions, and a function defined piecewise is still 'exact'.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Discontinuous points come from common factors in the numerator and denominator, so you should be able to find two factors of the denominator from item 3.  Since you have no $x$ intercepts, the function should not go through zero, and it sounds like you don't want vertical asymptotes.  It looks like a nice graph that satisfies your needs would be the line $y=-5$ less the two discontinuous points.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I know how to do every step of this problem, but I was caught with the 'no x intercepts' part; I forgot to tell you that the answer to this graph isn't supposed to be linear.

Comment: You can multiply it by a quadratic factor.  If you pick a quadratic that is always positive and has value $1$ at $x=-1$ and $x=3$ you will be there.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\left(\frac{x+1}{\left| x+1\right|}\right)\left(\frac{x-3}{\left|x-3\right|}\right)-4$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sin(2\pi x)-7+\left(\frac{x+1}{x+1}\right)+\left(\frac{x-3}{x-3}\right)$$

Explanation:
$\sin$ term to make it non-linear and no x intercept

$-7$ to account for y intercept

Fractional terms to account for discontinuities (You can only simplify those to $1$ if $x\neq-1$ or $3$)